# Setting audio.playbackRate will cause the mp3 to skip in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, audio

Has anyone noticed that:
 `document.querySelector("audio").playbackRate = 1.5`

Causes a slight skip each time it is changed. Does anyone know a fix for this? Even if requires Cordova?

Go to http://daniemon.com/tech/html5/playbackRate/ on iPhone, change the playbackrate and you will get the slight skip.

We are updating playbackrate regularly and it is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that even the official iPhone Podcast application among other native approaches cause the slight skip when adjusting bpm/tempo. However, there are apps available on iOS that can make audio speed up without a skip.